# Filtering by flight times in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have flight delays ranging from hours ahead of schedule to delays of all durations. I need to countif any delay that is longer than 20 minutes. The values in the column take on this format: "-0:22:00" (without the quotes). I do get conditional formatting to work when using a less than -00:20:00.000 figure, but extracting/querying those rows based on the < 20 threshold isn't working. I know the formula is something like =COUNTIF(myDataSheet!P$2:P,"<0:20:00"). . . can anyone let me know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(myDataSheet!P2:P,"<"&-time(0,20,0))
```